# C++ lock tabskbar on WM6.1 but also lock windows key

Tags: c++, windows, mobile

I have a code below to lock the Taskbar(the top window bar on the screen on WM6.1) but it also locks the windows key.  The windows key is working before running the code, but after running the code, the Taskbar is locked but also windows key is not responding on pressed. How can I lock the taskbar only?

thanks.

```
TaskBar(BOOL lock)
{
    if(lock == TRUE)
    {
        CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindowW(TEXT("HHTaskBar"), NULL);

        if(pWnd)
        {
            pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_HIDE);
            pWnd->EnableWindow(FALSE);                    
        }
    }
    else if(lock == FALSE)
    {
        CWnd* pWnd = CWnd::FindWindowW(TEXT("HHTaskBar"), NULL);

        if(pWnd)
        {
            pWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOWNORMAL);
            pWnd->EnableWindow(TRUE);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to lock the taskbar, then remove the code EnableWindows(boolean).  But just to let you know that windows 6.1 has Start/Windows icon sharing with the taskbar so it will lock that Start\Windows button too.

Answer (score 0):

Your question doesn't really make any sense. You're *disabling* the taskbar. The only thing the winkey does when pressed on its own is open the taskbar.

Use a key handler to detect press of the winkey, re-enable the taskbar to show, then disable it again if that's what you really want.

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I thought locking the tashbar has nothing to do with windows key, but somehow it affects the windows key as well.  My goal is to enable or disable taskbar to control the clicking on app icons in taskbar, but windows key should behave what's supposed to.

Comment: Well, I just told you how to do that.

Comment: But the thing is that as soon as I enable the taskbar to enable the windows key, user can freely click on other app icons in the taskbar area which I really don't want that.

Comment: after thought over again, maybe that is good idea you suggested.  I can create CALLBACK to look for key stroke then when it gets WM_KEYDOWN, I can enable the taskbar, but will disable the taskbar as soon windows key is released, WM_KEYUP.  But not sure in that split second when receiving KEYDOWN then enable tashbar, will taskbar can trigger the windows/start to give drop-dowm menu list.

Comment: I tired it, but have no luck.  I can catch key stroke then enable the taskbar but when press on windows key is not responding.